# Finding the residue

Tags: residue-calculus

Finding the fourth derivative in order to get residue seems me  very complicated, is there another way? $$Res\left( z=i,\frac { { e }^{ iz } }{ { \left( { z }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }^{ 5 } }  \right) =\lim _{ z\rightarrow i }{ \frac { 1 }{ 4! } \frac { { d }^{ 4 } }{ { d }{ z }^{ 4 } } \left( { \left( z-i \right)  }^{ 5 }\frac { { e }^{ iz } }{ { \left( z-i \right)  }^{ 5 }{ \left( z+i \right)  }^{ 5 } }  \right)  } $$

Comment: You can try the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: What do you need this for? If you are only interested in the result, then have a look: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+of++e%5E%7Bix%7D%2F(x%5E2%2B1)%5E5++at+x%3Di

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful, but you could also try to integrate the function around the singularity.

Comment: I need another way as i mentioned above,wolframalpha  gives an answer which i don't want before getting solution

Comment: @klirk,finding integral demands  to find residue either

Comment: Not necessarily. You could take a loop, parametrize it and calculate the integral without knowing anything about the residue theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the residuum  is the coefficient of $(z-i)^{-1}$ in the Laurent-series expansion of $\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^5}$ at  $z=i$, we can  expand the function and extract  the coefficient.

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{Res}}&\color{blue}{\left( z=i,\frac { { e }^{ iz } }{ { \left( { z }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }^{ 5 } }  \right)}\\
> &=\mathrm{Res}\left(t=0,\frac{e^{i(t+i)}}{t^5(t+2i)^5}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=[t^{-1}]\frac{e^{i(t+i)}}{t^5(t+2i)^5}\tag{2}\\
> &=[t^4]\frac{e^{i(t+i)}}{(t+2i)^5}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(2i)^5}[t^4]e^{i(t+i)}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{j}\left(\frac{t}{2i}\right)^j\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{32ie}[t^4]e^{it}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+4}{j}\left(-\frac{t}{2i}\right)^j\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{32ie}\left(\frac{i^0}{0!}\binom{8}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^4+\frac{i^1}{1!}\binom{7}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^3
> +\frac{i^2}{2!}\binom{6}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\frac{i^3}{3!}\binom{5}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^1+\frac{i^4}{4!}\binom{4}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^0\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{1}{32ie}\left(\frac{35}{8}+\frac{35}{8}+\frac{15}{8}+\frac{5}{12}+\frac{1}{24}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{133i}{384e}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the residuum to $0$ by setting $t=z-i$.
- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* $[t^n]$ operator to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ in a series.
- In (3) we apply the rule $[t^{p-q}]A(t)=[t^p]t^qA(t)$.
- In (4) we factor out $(2i)^5$ and use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (5) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $t^4$, by recalling $e^{it}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(it)^k}{k!}$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution

Comment: @haqnatural: You're welcome.